# Printing out information from a file by looping through another function designed to search the file - C++

Tags: c++, file-io, printing, addressbook

I have this function that can scan my file and print out a predesignated record according to which one you choose to look at:

```
void addressBook::showRecord(int pickNum) {
  PEOPLE2 p;
  ifstream indata("vectortest.dat", ios::binary);
  if(!indata) {
    cout << "Error opening file for reading " << endl;
    exit(0);
  }
  indata.seekg(pickNum * sizeof(PEOPLE2));
  indata.read(reinterpret_cast <char*> (&p), sizeof(PEOPLE2));
  cout << p.fName2 << " " << p.lName2 << " " << p.Address2 << " " << endl;
}
```

So all you have to do is pop showRecord into main, and then pick which name you want to print out. Say I want to look at the second name stored, I would put in

```
newBook->showRecord(1);
```

Thats all fine an dandy, and it works perfect, but what if I want to go a bit further. So I create another function that can use showRecord to print out all of the names in the address book that have been stored to my file. I tried this:

```
void addressBook::showAll() {
  ifstream indata("vectortest.dat", ios::binary);
  for(int i = 0; i < indata.end; i++) {
    showRecord(i);
  }
}
```

and it works, but it only prints out the stuff that's hard coded into my PERSON struct from a previous assignment:

```
addressBook *newBook = addressBook::newbookInst(); 

PERSON me[] = {{"First" , "Last", "ADDRESS"}, {"John", "Doe", "1234"}}; 
                    newBook->addPerson(me[1]); 

                    newBook->addPerson(me[0]);
```

which is just odd beacuse when I go into the file itself, I can see all of the names that were added.

So how do I use this so that it actually prints out everything in the file, and not just the two entries that are permanently stored?

Here is my addressbook.h and addressbook.cpp code in case you need a better understanding of whats going on...

\\addressbook.h////////

```
#ifndef _ADDRESSBOOK
#define _ADDRESSBOOK
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include<string>
using std::string;
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

using std::istream;
using std::ostream;
namespace CJ
{
const int MAXADDRESS =25;

struct PERSON
{
    string fName;
    string lName;
    string Address;
};
struct PEOPLE2
{
    char fName2[25];
    char lName2[25];
    char Address2[25];
};

class addressBook
{
private:

    vector<PERSON> people;

    int head;
    int tail;

public:

    addressBook();

    addressBook(const PERSON &p);
    addressBook(const PERSON p[], int size);
    addressBook(char *fName, char *lName, char *address);
    bool addPerson(const PERSON &p);
    bool sortcomp(const PERSON& p1, const PERSON& p2);
    bool getPerson(PERSON &p);
    bool findPerson(const string& lastName, PERSON& p);
    bool findPerson(const string& lastName, const string& firstName, PERSON& p);
    void bubbleSort(int *array,int length);
    void printBook();
    void sort();
    void waitKey();
    static addressBook *newbookInst();
    static addressBook *tempNew;
    static PERSON *p();
    static PERSON *temPerson;
    void showRecord(int pickNum);
    void writeRecord();
    void showAll();


    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &, addressBook &);
    addressBook operator =(const string& str);
    addressBook &operator +=(const PERSON &p); 
    addressBook operator [](int x); 

};
}
#endif
```

\\addressbook.cpp/////

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
using std::string;
#include "addressBook.h"
#include "menu.h"
namespace CJ
{
addressBook::addressBook()
    : head(0), tail(-1)
{

}

addressBook::addressBook(const PERSON &p)
    : head(0), tail(-1)
{
    addPerson(p);
}

addressBook::addressBook(const PERSON p[], int size)
    : head(0), tail(-1)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        addPerson(p[i]);

}

addressBook::addressBook(char *fName, char *lName, char *Address)
    : head(0), tail(-1)
{
    PERSON tmp;
    tmp.fName = fName;
    tmp.lName = lName;
    tmp.Address = Address;
    addPerson(tmp);
}

bool addressBook::addPerson(const PERSON &p)
{
    people.push_back(p);

    if(tail == -1)
        tail++;
    return true; 
}

bool addressBook::getPerson(PERSON &p)
{
    if(tail >=0)
    {
        if(tail >= people.size())
            tail = 0;
        p = people[tail];
        tail++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
bool addressBook::findPerson(const string &lastName, PERSON &p)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < people.size(); i++)
    {
        if(people[i].lName == lastName)
        {
            PERSON *p = addressBook::p();
            *p = people[i];
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
bool addressBook::findPerson(const string &lastName, const string &firstName, PERSON &p)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < people.size(); i++)
    {
        if(people[i].lName == lastName && people[i].fName == firstName)
        {
            PERSON *p = addressBook::p();
            *p = people[i];
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


void addressBook::printBook()
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < people.size(); i++)
    {       
        std::cout << people[i].fName << "\t" << people[i].lName << "\t" << people[i].Address << std::endl;
    }
}


bool addressBook::sortcomp(const PERSON& p1, const PERSON& p2)
{
    int result = (p1.lName.compare(p2.lName)) ;
    if ( result > 0 )
        return true ;
    if ( result < 0 )
        return false ;
    return (p1.fName.compare(p2.fName)) > 0 ;
}

void addressBook::sort() 
{
    bool didSwap ;
    do
    {
        didSwap = false ;

        for ( unsigned i=1; i<people.size(); ++i )
            if ( sortcomp(people[i-1], people[i]) )
            {
                std::swap(people[i-1], people[i]) ;
                didSwap = true ;
            }

    } while ( didSwap ) ;
}

addressBook &addressBook::operator +=(const PERSON &p)
{
    addPerson(p);
    return *this;
};

addressBook addressBook::operator [](int x)
{
    return people[x];
};

ostream &operator << (ostream &output, addressBook &ab)
{
    PERSON tmp;
    ab.getPerson(tmp);
    output << tmp.fName << " " << tmp.lName << " " << tmp.Address << endl;
    return output;
}

addressBook * addressBook::tempNew = NULL;
addressBook *addressBook::newbookInst()
{
    if(tempNew == NULL)
    {
        tempNew = new addressBook;
    }
    return tempNew;
}

PERSON * addressBook::temPerson = NULL;
PERSON *addressBook::p()
{
    if(temPerson == NULL)
    {
        temPerson = new PERSON;
    }
    return temPerson;
}
bool status;
char lName[50];
char fName[50];

void addressBook::writeRecord()
{

PEOPLE2 temp;
ofstream outFile("vectortest.dat", ios::app);
    if(!outFile)
    {
        cout << "Error opening file for writing " << endl;
        return;
    }

        for (vector<PERSON>::iterator iter = people.begin(), end = people.end(); iter != end; ++iter)
        {
        strncpy(temp.fName2, iter->fName.c_str(), 25);
        strncpy(temp.lName2, iter->lName.c_str(), 25);
        strncpy(temp.Address2, iter->Address.c_str(), 25);
        outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&temp), sizeof(PEOPLE2));
        }       
    outFile.close();
}


void addressBook::showRecord(int pickNum)
{
PEOPLE2 p;

ifstream indata("vectortest.dat", ios::binary);
    if(!indata)
    {
        cout << "Error opening file for reading " << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    indata.seekg(pickNum * sizeof(PEOPLE2));
    indata.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&p), sizeof(PEOPLE2));
    cout << p.fName2 << " " << p.lName2 << " " << p.Address2 << " " << endl;

    indata.close();

}

void addressBook::showAll()
{
ifstream indata("vectortest.dat", ios::binary);

for(int i = 0; i  < indata.end; i ++)
{
    showRecord(i);
}

}



}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it only prints out the stuff that's hard coded into my PERSON struct from a previous assignment"? AND, what is `indata.end`? It is not the number of records, is it?

Comment: I'll pop that code in the main post to show what its doing

Comment: Also, will you post the declaration of `PEOPLE2` please?

Comment: I think it is not good idea to call showRecord() within showAll(), because you create and destroy many times an I/O object. Is not so difficult to write a special function... Maybe the problem will be solved.

Comment: I used indata.end assuming that it would look at that for the size of the file and know how many times it had to loop until it prints to the end of the file

Comment: Current code opens the file *twice*, once in `showAll()` and again in `showRecord()`. Since `showRecord()` is going to open it anyway, it is not necessary to open the file in `showAll()`. Can you remove the line [`ifstream indata("vectortest.dat", ios::binary);`] and try?

Comment: If I do that then I have to find something else to loop through to, since I can't call on indata anymore, it just tells me that indata is undefined

Comment: and if i just got with ifstream indata;, it still jus tpops up the two names from PERSON, and nothing else

Comment: Anyone have an idea on this? Or should I just give it up and find some other way to do this that doesn't involve looping this type of function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know that much about the context of how you're planning to use your address book class. But what I've done is re-work the basic structure of what you had into a little more idiomatic C++. This should hopefully help guide your future work on this class. The reading from file issue that you were having issues with is fixed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

const int MAXADDRESS = 25;

struct PEOPLE2
{
    char fName2[25];
    char lName2[25];
    char Address2[25];
};

struct PERSON
{
    PERSON()
    {}
    PERSON(PEOPLE2 p) 
        : fName(p.fName2), lName(p.lName2), Address(p.Address2)
    {}
    PERSON(const std::string& first, const std::string& last, const std::string& add)
        : fName(first), lName(last), Address(add)
    {}
    std::string fName;
    std::string lName;
    std::string Address;
};
// required for std::sort
bool operator< (const PERSON &lhs, const PERSON &rhs)
{
    int result = (lhs.lName.compare(rhs.lName));
    if(result == 0)
        return lhs.fName < rhs.fName;
    return result < 0;
}
// required for os << people
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const PERSON& rhs)
{
    os << rhs.fName << " " << rhs.lName << " " << rhs.Address;
    return os;
}

class addressBook
{
private:
    std::vector<PERSON> people;

public:

    addressBook()
    { }

    addressBook(const PERSON &p)
    {
        addPerson(p);
    }

    template<typename IT>
    addressBook(IT begin, IT end)
    {
        std::copy(begin, end, std::back_inserter(people));
    }

    addressBook(char *fName, char *lName, char *address)
    {
        PERSON tmp;
        tmp.fName = fName;
        tmp.lName = lName;
        tmp.Address = address;
        addPerson(tmp);
    }

    addressBook(const std::string& fileName)
    {
        std::ifstream indata(fileName, std::ios::binary);

        PEOPLE2 p;
        while(true)
        {
            indata.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&p), sizeof(PEOPLE2));
            if(indata.fail())
                break;
            people.push_back(p);
        }
    }

    void addPerson(const PERSON &p)
    {
        people.push_back(p);
    }

    bool findPerson(const std::string& lastName, PERSON& p)
    {
        std::find_if(std::begin(people), std::end(people), [&](const PERSON& in)->bool
        {
            if(lastName == in.lName)
            {
                p = in;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

    bool findPerson(const std::string& lastName, const std::string& firstName, PERSON& p)
    {
        std::find_if(std::begin(people), std::end(people), [&](const PERSON& in)->bool
        {
            if(lastName == in.lName && firstName == in.fName)
            {
                p = in;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

    void printBook()
    {
        std::for_each(std::begin(people), std::end(people), [](const PERSON& p)
        {       
            std::cout << p.fName << "\t" << p.lName << "\t" << p.Address << std::endl;
        });
    }

    void sort()
    {
        std::sort(std::begin(people),std::end(people));
    }

    void waitKey();

    void showRecord(int pickNum)
    {
        std::cout << people[pickNum] << std::endl;
    }

    void writeRecord(const std::string& fileName)
    {

        PEOPLE2 temp;
        std::ofstream outFile(fileName, std::ios::app);
        if(!outFile)
        {
            std::cout << "Error opening file for writing " << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        for(auto iter = people.begin(), end = people.end(); iter != end; ++iter)
        {
            strncpy(temp.fName2, iter->fName.c_str(), 25);
            strncpy(temp.lName2, iter->lName.c_str(), 25);
            strncpy(temp.Address2, iter->Address.c_str(), 25);
            outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&temp), sizeof(PEOPLE2));
        }       
    }

    void showAll()
    {
        std::for_each(std::begin(people), std::end(people), [](const PERSON& in)
        {
                std::cout << in << std::endl;
        });
    }


    friend std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &output, addressBook &ab)
    {
        std::for_each(std::begin(ab.people), std::end(ab.people), [&](const PERSON& in)
        {
            output << in << "\n";
        });
        return output;
    }

    addressBook &operator +=(const PERSON &p)
    {
        addPerson(p);
        return *this;
    };

    PERSON operator [](int x)
    {
        return people[x];
    };

};

std::string fileName = "c:\\temp\\test.rec";
int main()
{
    addressBook ab(fileName);
    ab.sort();
    ab.showAll();

    //addressBook ab;
    //ab.addPerson(PERSON("Mary", "Smith", "1 West Street"));
    //ab.addPerson(PERSON("Joe", "Brown", "2 East Street"));
    //ab.addPerson(PERSON("Harry", "Cooper", "3 South Street"));
    //ab.writeRecord(fileName);
}
```

Comment: WOW! It's going to take me a little while to understand some of the changes you made, but what I do understand makes a ton of sense. I had always thought my PERSON struct should look like you've done it, but the teacher doesn't want it that way. I'm going to work with this because you've actually done stuff here that just seems way more efficient then what we've been doing. Granted, its a class, so keeping it simple is probably the point, but I like this, thanks!